# Sprite saving position, sfml. Battlesgips game

Tags: sfml, tile

I'm a newbie in a programming, And now I'm learning sfml.

I have a problem with some game,  and my question is

How I can make sprites save position after pressing a key?

It should save its positing after pressing a key. After it cannot be moved.
Then another sprite should appear, then i can none it, then I'll save its position and etc..

It is battleships game.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried so far, e.g. by posting the relevant code. This way we can address the problem more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `Sprite::getPosition()`

then store it in a `sf::Vector2f` object like this:

```
//assume we have sprite object called spr
sf::Vector2f savedPosition = spr.getPosition();
```

Comment: So after this, it will not move, yeah?

Comment: for that you have to have condition which when satisfies will move the sprite

Answer (score -1):

Try saving the position of sprite in a variable.
Direct the sprite to the variable continuously.
For changing position of sprite just change the variable.

Comment: changing the variable wont move the sprite